# While loop not behaving as expected

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, netbeans

I am working in an assignment and am experiencing some weird stuff. I have this while loop in my program that does not seem to branch into the for loop. I have placed two print statements and only the "1" prints over and over again. Note that this only happens when  I compile and run from the linux terminal. Now what seem weird is that if i run the exact same code (while loop plus everything else) in Netbeans it seems to compile and behave as expected. Anyone know what might be wrong. Here is the code. I appreciate your help.

```
while(strstr(p,string_a)!= NULL)
{
    p = trailerp + pholderp; 
    long int index =  strstr(p,string_a) - (p+1); // -1 where it hits 
    printf("1");
    for(  i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        printf("2");
        p2[trailerp2] = pholderp[trailerp];
        trailerp++;
        trailerp2++;
        if(i == index)
        {  
            int j;
            for(j=0; j <= lenb-1; j++)            // insert the new string
            {
                p2[trailerp2] = string_b[j];
                trailerp2++;
            }
            trailerp++;
        }       
    }  
}
```

Edit: I have found the problem. Netbeans seems to be broken in this OS.

Comment: It might help if you fixed your formatting.

Comment: This sounds like you don't have a variable initialized properly.

Comment: You really should learn to compile with warnings and debugging info (e.g. pass `-Wall -g` to the `gcc` compiler) and you should learn to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `strstr(p,string_a)` returns either `p` or `0` in this part:

```
long int index =  strstr(p,string_a) - (p+1); // -1 where it hits
```

which results in `index < 0` and prevents going into the loop.

You must print both `p` and `string_a` immediately before this statement to see what is going wrong there.